# Python script using curses fails on macOS

Tags: macos, ncurses, curses, python-curses

I'm trying to run the [`nettop.py`](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/scripts/nettop.py) script from the [`psutil`](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) repository using Python 3.6.4. It's primarily meant to demonstrate the usage of Python's `psutil` module.

It's working fine on Ubuntu, but running it on macOS fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nettop.py", line 167, in <module>
    main()
  File "nettop.py", line 160, in main
    refresh_window(*args)
  File "nettop.py", line 138, in refresh_window
    stats_after.bytes_recv - stats_before.bytes_recv) + '/s',
  File "nettop.py", line 67, in print_line
    win.addstr(lineno, 0, line, 0)
_curses.error: addwstr() returned ERR
```

That `win` object in the last line of the Traceback is defined in [`nettop.py:53`](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/95b8e4ba7c2f90d6239266890212feb4031c6bed/scripts/nettop.py#L53) and comes from the `curses` module:

```
win = curses.initscr()
```

I have no idea where that `addwstr()` function comes from.

Can someone shed some light on this? Any ideas on how I could get this to run on macOS?

Comment: Hmm, I ran this on my Mac (Python 3.6.0, but close enough I imagine) and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @cag51 That's strange. I even get the same result as described above on a freshly installed macOS (in a VM) with the built in Python 2.7.10.

Comment: Okay, now I get it. It just so happens that I have way more interfaces on the Mac than on the Ubuntu machine, so on the Mac, the terminal is not big enough to fit the output for all the interfaces but on the Ubuntu machine the output is much smaller and therefore fits without causing the error. Whether it's macOS or Ubuntu is just coincidental.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screensize is probably relevant, since it's assuming that a full set of messages will be written before it resets the **`lineno`** variable to zero at the end of the loop.

The **`print_line`** function aggravates that by raising an exception rather than checking for the conditions which would cause the curses *addstr* to return an error:

- line too line
- line past the end of the screen

For example, here's a (crude) workaround for that:

```
diff --git a/scripts/nettop.py b/scripts/nettop.py
index e13903c1..d263eb99 100755
--- a/scripts/nettop.py
+++ b/scripts/nettop.py
@@ -59,9 +59,11 @@ lineno = 0
 def print_line(line, highlight=False):
     """A thin wrapper around curses's addstr()."""
     global lineno
+    if lineno >= win.getmaxyx()[0]:
+        lineno = win.getmaxyx()[0] - 1
     try:
         if highlight:
-            line += " " * (win.getmaxyx()[1] - len(line))
+            line += " " * (win.getmaxyx()[1] - len(line) - 1)
             win.addstr(lineno, 0, line, curses.A_REVERSE)
         else:
             win.addstr(lineno, 0, line, 0)
```

which doesn't go very deep (since the script also assumes the screen is always wide enough).

Whether it calls [**`addstr`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addstr.3x.html#h2-RETURN-VALUE) or [**`addwstr`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addwstr.3x.html#h2-RETURN-VALUE) underneath does not matter much, since both make the same sort of checks.